# power calculation

Tags: electrical

In a perfect world, there should be a constant assigned to the angle difference between voltage and current , no inductance.   I suppose the angle is unique to the amount of inductance in each circuit. Even a straight wire has a certain amount of inductance. The frequency of the AC voltage would determine the reactance of each component in the circuit. Both resistance and reactance impede current flow . In a circuit with a steady frequency, would the capacitive reactance and inductive reactance be combined with the resistance and multiplied by the average voltage to give the actual wattage ? The reststance, reactance would be determined using the rules for determining resistance for a circuit ?

Comment: V and I are related by impedance and phase angle in sinusoidal AC. See [here](http://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/18.03-esg/notes/complexImpedance.pdf) for a very concise summary of the math. It gives you the terminology if you want to Google further.

Comment: @rul30 There is a measure of overlap between this site and the electronics.SE site.  This question is on topic for here, too.

Comment: this falls in the category of "not *really* off topic but you would be better of on a more appropriate site"